# Tabulate Area Errors

Tags: arcmap, spatial-analyst

Having some issues with the tabulate area spatial analyst tool. Not sure why it's not working, but the output table is missing zones from the input feature class that defines them.

I have a simple raster with 3 values. I'd like to simply find out the amount of cells that lie in each zone of the polygon. The tabulate tool should do this no problem.

But, after the tool runs, the output table only has about 1800 records. The original input zone polygon has around 5000. Any ideas on why this tool is failing so badly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that of course this is an ESRI issue. The actual Tabulate Area tool cannot handle massive datasets.